# React Navigation Nested Stacks, accessing Root stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Is there a way to access a root stack navigator from an inner stack navigator? For example:

```
const Root = StackNavigator(
{
  Login: {
      screen: Login,
    },
    TabNav: {
      screen: TabNav    
    }
}
);

const TabNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    Content: {
      screen: Content,
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack
    }
  }
);
```

Within that SettingsStack screen I have a logout button. How would I access the Root Stack to navigate back to Login? Rather than that inner stack in the Tab Navigation just pushing to the login page within the child stack.

Comment: @bob from `TabNav` in StackNavigator pass a function as a screenProp to `TabNavigator` . Now whenever you want to logout call that function

Comment: Would I need to pass the props into SettingsStack similarly?

Comment: I suppose you would have to do so . Cauz SettingsStack is a Navigator inside another navigator

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Posting it as an answer for others to benefit .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `TabNav` in StackNavigator pass a function as a screenProp to `TabNavigator` . Use the function whenever you want to logout. Since `SettingsStack` is a navigator inside another navigator pass the props into `SettingsStack` to make it work.